# Handle date and time for different timezones

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, timezone

I'm working on a feature of an app where users can create groups, and each group can have multiple posts. The groups have a start and end date. I'm using Node.js for the backend and PostgreSQL to model the data. The tables look like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."group"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    start_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    end_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    owner_id uuid
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."post"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    group_id uuid,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
```

A user can only post to a specific group once a day and the days in which they post should be recorded (users will be able to see in a "progress calendar" the days in which other people in the group and themselves created a post). Users from different countries may enter the same group.

**How should I approach the following problems:**

**1. Make sure the user doesn't post more than once a day.**

Here I could just create a query which checks if the user already
posted on day X. The problem is not knowing the user's
timezone, as the server's timezone is generally used. Should I just
store users' location in the database when they create an account
and use the timezone from there? What if they move? I also thought
about sending a timezone along with the request, but that doesn't
seem like a good idea, as a malicious user could send anything
there.

**2. Sync the progress calendars for users with different time zones (e.g. user X from Romania, at 1 AM 22 August, should not see an x-mark in user's Y calendar for the date of 21 August, denoting that user Y hasn't posted on that date, as user Y still has time to post (user Y's date/time is 21 August 6 PM).**

**3. Not as important as the other 2 - What's a good practice for choosing the start / end date timezone for the group, so that users are not surprised when the group starts / ends. I would go with UTC, but I'm not sure people having UTC-9 and UTC+9 would have a pleasant experience with this.**

Just to give an example, timestamp with timezone is represented as `2021-08-17 20:01:00.427+03` in postgres.

Comment: If you use `timestamp with time zone` and each session sets the `timezone` parameter correctly, you have to do nothing, because the database handles time zone conversions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry for the late reply. I don't think the timezones are handled correctly. Let's say a client from US makes a request, and the server is hosted in Europe. The timezone saved in the db in related to the server, not the client.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't save the timezone with a `timestamp with time zone`. Rather, the value is converted to UTC, and when it is converted to a string again, it is formatted according to the `timezone` setting in the database session.